# PHP - Sentence group by 3 words, then get the first occurrence when the group changes

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm not sure how to explain it but this is the code:

```
$word = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
$word_length = strlen($word);
$space_count = 1;
for ($i=0;$i<=$word_length-1;$i++) 
{
            
            
            if ($word[$i] == ' ')
            {
                $space_count++;
            }

            if ($space_count <= 3) //1st set
            {
                echo 'set1 ';
            }
            elseif ($space_count > 3 && $space_count <= 6) //2nd set
            {
                echo 'set2 ';
            }
            elseif ($space_count > 6 && $space_count <= 9) //3rd set
            {
                echo 'set3 ';
            }
            elseif ($space_count > 9) //4th set
            {
                echo 'set4 ';
            }

            echo $word[$i].'<br/>';
}
```

Output is:

```
set1 T
set1 h
set1 e
set1
set1 q
set1 u
set1 i
set1 c
set1 k
set1
set1 b
set1 r
set1 o
set1 w
set1 n
set2
set2 f
set2 o
set2 x
set2
set2 j
set2 u
set2 m
set2 p
set2 s
set2
set2 o
set2 v
set2 e
set2 r
set3
set3 t
set3 h
set3 e
set3
set3 l
set3 a
set3 z
set3 y
set3
set3 d
set3 o
set3 g
set3 .
```

So I have already properly group each word/letter into 3 groups/sets. Now what I am stuck is when I now change to a new set/group. I need to identify the first time that a group changes. So in this case - I need to know that set 2 starts with "f" which is the first word for "fox". Then 3rd set starts with "t" which is the first word of "the".

I need to know this since I have to do an additional condition when the first occurrence of the group/set changes. Hope you could help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way and more dynamic as your stuck with only 3 sets.

Work to make an array, then first char for any set would be `[0][0]`, for example:

```
<?php
$word = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

$sets = array_chunk(explode(' ',$word), 3);
$sets = array_combine(array_map(function($key){ return 'set'.($key+1); }, array_keys($sets)), $sets);

/*
Array
(
    [set1] => Array
        (
            [0] => The
            [1] => quick
            [2] => brown
        )

    [set2] => Array
        (
            [0] => fox
            [1] => jumps
            [2] => over
        )

    [set3] => Array
        (
            [0] => the
            [1] => lazy
            [2] => dog.
        )

)
*/

// then to grab first chars
// f
echo $sets['set2'][0][0];

// t
echo $sets['set3'][0][0];
```

https://3v4l.org/TOFbo

To get total sets you only need to `count($sets)`, to get only one set you only need `$set['set1']`, to get all first words in all sets you only need `array_column($sets, '0')`, to get all keys/sets `array_keys($sets)`. Vastly simpler than looping over every char and counting things.

then/or to put it back together, re-loop over it:

```
$str = '';
foreach ($sets as $set) $str .= implode(' ', $set).' ';
echo trim($str);
```

or using reduce:

```
echo trim(array_reduce($sets, function($acc, $set) {
    return $acc .= implode(' ', $set).' ';
}, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to *keep your existing set of logic rules* (e.g. if you have further plans for extending them), you can create an array and save each character for a particular "set" into a sub-array with a key, e.g. "set1". Then you can get any character from any set like this:

```
$sets[$set_key][$char_pos];
// e.g.
echo $sets["set1"][0];
echo $sets["set2"][0];
echo $sets["set3"][0];
```

FYI This mimics your current result of having all sets after set1 starting with a space, as it uses your existing rules. (If this isn't what you intend to do, you might need to adapt your rules)

**Your adapted code:**

```
$word = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
$word_length = strlen($word);
$space_count = 1;
$sets = array();

for ($i=0;$i<=$word_length-1;$i++) {
        
        if ($word[$i] == ' ')
        {
            $space_count++;
        }

        if ($space_count <= 3) //1st set
        {
            $sets['set1'][] = $word[$i];
        }
        elseif ($space_count > 3 && $space_count <= 6) //2nd set
        {
            $sets['set2'][] = $word[$i];
        }
        elseif ($space_count > 6 && $space_count <= 9) //3rd set
        {
            $sets['set3'][] = $word[$i];
        }
        elseif ($space_count > 9) //4th set
        {
            $sets['set4'][] = $word[$i];
        }
}
print_r($sets);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [set1] => Array
        (
            [0] => T
            [1] => h
            [2] => e
            [3] =>  
            [4] => q
            [5] => u
            [6] => i
            [7] => c
            [8] => k
            [9] =>  
            [10] => b
            [11] => r
            [12] => o
            [13] => w
            [14] => n
        )

    [set2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] => f
            [2] => o
            [3] => x
            [4] =>  
            [5] => j
            [6] => u
            [7] => m
            [8] => p
            [9] => s
            [10] =>  
            [11] => o
            [12] => v
            [13] => e
            [14] => r
        )

    [set3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
            [1] => t
            [2] => h
            [3] => e
            [4] =>  
            [5] => l
            [6] => a
            [7] => z
            [8] => y
            [9] =>  
            [10] => d
            [11] => o
            [12] => g
            [13] => .
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is obviously the [Lawrence's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63803712/3950328). It's elegant and performant ([PHP's array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) are extremely performant compared to a for loop or anything you can code by yourself)

But to basically answer your question and keep your logic if you are not comfortable with those functions. I suggest to use a [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) test :

```
$word = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
$word_length = strlen($word);
$space_count = 0;
$j = 1;
$check_spacing = false;
for ($i=0;$i<=$word_length-1;$i++)
{
    if ($word[$i] == ' ')
    {
        $space_count++;
        // we have a space, so we need to test if it's the third or not
        $check_spacing = true;
        continue;
    }
    // Enter in it every 3 spaces or if it's the first char of your sentence.
    if ($i == 0 || ($space_count % 3 == 0 && $check_spacing))
    {
        // So we'll not test the condition before the next space character
        $check_spacing = false;
        echo sprintf('The first letter of set %s is %s <br>', $j++, $word[$i]);
    }
}
```

With this, you should have something like this and it's working for every sentence length :

> The first letter of set 1 is T

> The first letter of set 2 is f

> The first letter of set 3 is t

Comment: Lawrence's is of course the most elegant solution, but when the OP hasn't made their full intention clear, IMO it is usually safest to go for the least intrusive option with the fewest changes to get to what they asked for. My assumption is that they want to use their "sets" so I kept them exactly as per their code. Not elegant, but it is what they (appear to have) asked for :)